# NSCollectionView grid display only one row

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I have a NSCollectionView with follow parameters:

[image]

And have a custom `NSCollectionViewItem` with `WebView` to dispaly html pages

```
extension ViewController : NSCollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ itemForRepresentedObjectAtcollectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

        let item = htmlNotificationsCollectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "htmlNotificationCollectionViewItem", for: indexPath)
        return item
    }
}
```

My code is working but it only display one item ! And ignore `numberOfSections` to display vertically

If i change `numberOfItemsInSection` to 3 it display 3 items, but horizontally.

I need layout like this:

[image]

Comment: "If i change numberOfItemsInSection to 3 it display 3 items, but horizontally."  It depends on the window size.

Comment: @El Tomato yes, scroll appears , but how make them vertical. It shows one item with any size...

Answer (score 3):

You should set maximumNumberOfColumns programmatically:

```
let layout = NSCollectionViewGridLayout()
    layout.maximumNumberOfColumns = 1
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

(for some reasons when you setup Grid properties on a Storyboard it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

NSCollectionViewGridLayout is single sectioned layout. By Apple documentation, this means the layout can hold only one section.

> A layout that displays a single section of items in a row and column grid.

That's why you are not getting any more sections.

Change it to NSCollectionViewFlowLayout to get more than one sections. Hope this helped.